# not able to find template section in Azure app logic section

Tags: azure

I want to create automated threat response in Microsoft Defender for Cloud. For this, I want to create a logic app first. I am using the following link to complete this lab.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/workflow-automation

I am stuck at the 6th point as I cannot find templates in my newly created logic app. Can anyone guide me on how to complete this lab? I am using a free trial subscription. Pls let me know possible mistakes that I should repair to complete this lab.

also, while creating an automation workflow, my newly created logic app is not visible even after clicking refresh. What could be the possible mistake?[Not able to find newly created logic app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je2xZ.png)[not getting templates section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH4JZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will find predefined templates only in `consumption plan` not in Standard Logic app or any other plan.

[image]

You will get default templates when you open your Logic app.

[image]